# Using a Number Range in a Where Statement

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, numbers, where-clause

I'm trying to use a number range in a `Where` statement while iterating through a `foreach` loop. The `$i` variable is being used to separate parts of the loop depending on how many iterations the loop has been through.

```
$a = 11..20
$i = 0
$PoolSW = ""
$PoolSW2 = ""
$PoolSW3 = ""

foreach ($Pool in $PoolTable) {
    $i++
    [Array]$PoolSW += "Statistic.Pool$($Pool.Name -replace "-","_"): $(Get-PoolHealth -BooleanState $Pool.Enabled)" | where {$i -le 10}
    [Array]$PoolSW2 += "Statistic.Pool$($Pool.Name -replace "-","_"): $(Get-PoolHealth -BooleanState $Pool.Enabled)" | where {$i -eq $a}
    [Array]$PoolSW3 += "Statistic.Pool$($Pool.Name -replace "-","_"): $(Get-PoolHealth -BooleanState $Pool.Enabled)" | where {$i -gt 20}
}
```

The variables `$PoolSW` and `$PoolSW3` are working perfectly, unfortunately I don't know how to get `$PoolSW2` to work properly. I've tried `where {$i -eq 11..20}` and I've tried comma separating the numbers, I've tried `-contains` also.

Comment: Try `where {$i -in 11..20}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the range like -

```
... | where {$i -ge 11 -and $i -le 20}
```

**OR**

Use `-In` operator -

```
... | where {$i -in 11..20}
```